# simple constructor issue

Tags: c#

Lets say I have this class called class1, class1 contains one default constructor and one that takes one parameter (say a string for example). Inside that constructor I set up a variable, lets call it "string var". I want var to get the value from the string that I passed to the constructor while creating that object, but I want to be able to use var outside of the constructors scope, is that possible? since constructors doesen't return values and whatnot.

To clarify here is a code example of what I want to do:

```
class class1
{
    public class1(string songPath)
    {
        System.Media.SoundPlayer songPlayer = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(songPath);
    }
//here I want to use my songPlayer I created with the passed string as songPath
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make `songPlayer` a field - it is a local variable only visible to the constructor it is declared in at the moment.

```
private System.Media.SoundPlayer songPlayer;

public class1(string songPath)
{
    songPlayer = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(songPath);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great, will have good use of this in the future. Time to read up a bit on fields I guess.

Answer (score 1):

just create property like this

```
//System.Media.SoundPlayer _songPlayer ;
public System.Media.SoundPlayer songPlayer 
{
  //if you have nay logic to handle ull 
 //get{ if(_songPlayer != null)  return _songPlayer; else null; } or just 
   get;
}


public class1(string songPath)
{
     SongPlayer  = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(songPath);
    //_songPlayer  = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(songPath);
}
```

Note : helpful if you want to use this member outside class otherwise its better to go with @Oded solution..

And use private vriable for property if you want to handle null situation

Comment: What does the property add over a field?

Comment: @PranayRana But you don't handle the null value case; you just return null anyway, so it adds nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Another option for you might be a static class and method

```
public static class1(string songPath)
{
    public static System.Media.SoundPlayer play(string songPath)
    {
        System.Media.SoundPlayer songPlayer = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(songPath);
        // play here ?
        // or return to play
        return songPLayer;
    }
}
```